# Can you abbreviate the title of the Proceeedings of the IEEE?

Tags: citations, ieee

I found this on Page 34 of [IEEE EDITORIAL STYLE MANUAL](http://www.ieee.org/documents/style_manual.pdf), it's about how to edit the reference. I don't understand the following sentence:

> NOTE: The only exception to this rule is PROCEEDINGS OF THE IEEE, which never carried an acronym on the masthead

Does it mean when cite a paper from *PROCEEDINGS OF THE IEEE*, do not cite it in an abbreviation form. If it is, why the following example ( Page 35 of [IEEE EDITORIAL STYLE MANUAL](http://www.ieee.org/documents/style_manual.pdf)) gave an abbreviation form:

[image]

Comment: I would consider it an example of quality of IEEE outputs. You can be funny enough and ask them what does it mean. I'd really like to see their answer :D If you don't care enough to ask them, just choose one or the other. They don't actually expect people read the manual and they'll likely be happy either way.

Comment: I do not understand your comment, is my question so funny? or is my expression unclear?

Comment: Not every abbreviation is an acronym.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Sorry, I thought they are the same thing, here is the definition of `acronym`: `acronym: An abbreviation formed by (usually initial) letters taken from a word or series of words`. Then, what is the difference between them? I am not a native.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part you quote does not refer to the name of the Journal but to the vol. ##, no. ## section of the citation and is applicable to those earlier than 1988.

So the 1981 citation would be

- *IEEE Trans. Automat. Contr.,* **vol. AC-26**, no.1, pp. 1–34, Jan. 1981.

while a citation from the same journal past 1988 would be

- *IEEE Trans. Automat. Contr.,* **vol. 40**, no.1, pp. 1–34, Jan. 1995.

The exception to the Proc. of IEEE applies here, as it never had an abbreviation in the volume and it has always been:

- *Proc. IEEE*, vol. 11, no. 3, pp. 1-11, Jan. 1978.

The example they provide is correct.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it mean when cite a paper from PROCEEDINGS OF THE IEEE, do not cite it in an abbreviation form.

No.

It means that, prior to 1988 (see the style guide you linked to in your question), the volume number for IEEE *Journals* and *Transactions* included an acronym for the particular journal, and this must be included when you cite sources falling into this category. The *Proceedings of the IEEE* has never had volume numbers listed with an acronym for the publication, so the above volume number citation rule does not apply.

When citing a source published in the *Proceedings of the IEEE*, you would still list it in your IEEE manuscript bibliography as *Proc. IEEE*.